# what the meaning of (session?._id)

Tags: javascript, authentication, next.js, next-auth

```
export default NextAuth({
  ...
  callbacks: {
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
      if (session?.user) {
        session.user.id = token.uid;
      }
      return session;
    },
    jwt: async ({ user, token }) => {
      if (user) {
        token.uid = user.id;
      }
      return token;
    },
  },
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
  ...
});
```

Can anyone tell me the meaning of this statement -
`if (session?.user)` ?I really don't understand it.

1. Why is not like `if (session.user?)`
2. As I know the question mark operator should be follow by : to express when true and false situation. But why there is just "?"

Comment: It's called [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

session?.user is checking whether the session object exists and has a truthy user property before trying to access it.

If you write as session.user? it is not a valid syntax in JS

The ?. is called the optional chaining operator and the ? :  is conditional checking both are different things.

Answer (score 0):

in this example

```
let foo = undefined;
foo.example
```

This will throw an error if `foo` was undefined. To avoid this error, you can use:

```
let foo = undefined;
foo?.example
```